# File Upload in MEAN Stack with GridFS: Getting Errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongoose, mean, gridfs

Cheers mates!
I´m trying to make a file upload in my `MEAN Application` with GridFS. I´m using this tutorial http://www.codetutorial.io/file-upload-gridfs-mean-stack-meanjs/ .

After implementing it and checking it ten times, I still get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "filefield" of undefined` in the `upload.server.controller.js`. But it seems to me that the filefield is passed correctly to the route and to the controller.

**Here´s my html form:**

```
<form action="/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="filefield">
<button type="submit">Hochladen</button>
</form>
```

**The route:**

```
var upload = require ('./controllers/upload.server.controller');
app.route('/upload/:filename')
    .get(upload.read);
app.route('/upload/')
    .post(upload.create);
```

**And the create-part of the controller:**

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    _ = require ('lodash');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
var gfs = new Grid(mongoose.connection.db);

exports.create = function(req, res) {

    var part = req.files.filefield;

    var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: part.name,
        mode: 'w',
        content_type:part.mimetype
    });

    writeStream.on('close', function() {
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: 'Success'
        });
    });

    writeStream.write(part.data);

    writeStream.end();
};
```

Anybody got an idea how to fix this error?
Best regards from Germany,
David

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to include a body parser in your index.js file:

```
busboyBodyParser = require('busboy-body-parser'),
app.use(busboyBodyParser());
```

Without it there is no files in req object.

Comment: Can you debug or console.log what is in the req.files?

Comment: I put a console.log(req.files); direct above var part = req.files.filefield, where I get my console error. Getting "undefined"

Comment: So neither html form doesn't send a file or body-parser not work.
Try to upload file via curl like 

curl -XPOST -F ffilefield=@path/to/file url/upload

Comment: The TypeError is thrown at "Object.exports.create [as handle] and "Function.proto.process_params"

Answer (score 0):

You maybe have placed

```
  app.use(busboyBodyParser());
```

at the end. Try to place it upper. It will work.